# How do I track router change events in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to run a function every time the application switches URLs in Backbone.js, and I need to know the hashtag the URL has changed to. I'm assuming there is an event that I can bind to but I haven't been able to figure out which event and what object to bind to.

Specifically I want to ship the new URL to an analytics application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@qwertymk was half way there. You can look for the hashchange event on the **window** object:

```
// jQuery example
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

Comment: Note that this will not work for old versions of IE. (Check out the Backbone.js source - search for "oldIE".) You're better off using Theus G's solution.

Comment: What if the url is changing and not just the hash?

Answer (score 32):

I know this is an old post, but like @kirk suggested, Backbone.js already has it built it.

```
Backbone.history.on("all", function (route, router) {
    //console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

I think you'd be better off using this method.

Comment: I like this better than Thomas' solution, but I'm wondering why you have the $ before Backbone, and why you aren't using "bind" instead of "on"...

Comment: I suggest using "route" event instead of "all". Had double event firing when using "all". Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 4):

put this somewhere top in your code

```
Backbone.History.prototype.navigate = _.wrap(Backbone.History.prototype.navigate, function(){
    // Get arguments as an array
    var args = _.toArray(arguments);
    // firs argument is the original function
    var original = args.shift();
    // Set the before event
    Backbone.history.trigger('before:url-change', args);
    // Call original function
    var res = original.apply(this, args);
    // After event
    Backbone.history.trigger('url-changed');
    // Return original result
    return res;
});
```

the code above will wrap History.navigate function and will trigger "before:url-change" and "url-changed" when it is called

Later you can use

```
Backbone.history.bind('before:url-change', function(path,e){
    console.log("before url change", path, e)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Finally found an example that works!

Answer (score 2):

There is another, "Backbone.history.on('route', ...)" event, that works too and you can find it being triggered in the library):

> Backbone.history.on('route', function() { debugger; });

It is more precise, because 'all' is a catch all:
Quote from Backbone documentation:

> Trigger one or many events, firing all bound callbacks. Callbacks are passed the same arguments as `trigger` is, apart from the event name (unless you're listening on `"all"`, which will cause your callback to receive the true name of the event as the first argument).

By the way, Backbone best practice is to use listenTo method, e.g.:

> myView.listenTo(Backbone.history, 'route', function() { debugger; })

This way you don't need to clean up the event listener manually - instead it is logically bound to the view/model/etc. that uses it.