# How to use "hashchange" event in backbone.js event delegates?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, hashchange

In my backbone.js project, I need a method which triggered only when `window.location.hash` change. I found some alternative solution for my problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841418/how-do-i-track-router-change-events-in-backbone-js).

Also, I can solve this problem by creating a event in my backbone view `initialize function` as below

```
Backbone.View.extend({   
  initialize() {
      $(window).on('hashchange',()=> {
            console.log('yes hashchange events works')
      });
  }
```

But I seek for a solution which uses `backbone.js's` `eventDelegates` or `listenTo`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Backbone.history` for this scope.

> History serves as a global router (per frame) to handle hashchange
>   events or pushState, match the appropriate route, and trigger
>   callbacks. You shouldn't ever have to create one of these yourself
>   since Backbone.history already contains one.

Because it triggers a callback, you can listen for `hashchange` events:

```
Backbone.history.on("all", function (route, router) {
    console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

or

```
Backbone.history.on("route", function () {
    console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

Comment: it didn't work for me unfortunately, cause the `hashChange` option is set to `false` for Backbone.history, but this workaround did the trick:
´
window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.handleHashChange);´

Answer (score 0):

try this to initialize function:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function {
    var currentHash = location.hash;

    console.log('currentHash', currentHash);
})
```